# In .netcore 3.1 The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship

Tags: postgresql, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

Could anyone can help on this ?

We are migrating our application from .netcore 2.1 & vs2017 EntityFrameworkCore to .netcore 3.1 with vs 2019 and updated all the nuget packages to latest.

When we tried to fetch the record from a entity we got the below error and it works fine with vs 2017 & .netcore 2.1

***The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between
'MerchantSettings.Merchants' and 'MasterMerchants.MerchantSetting'. 
To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. 
If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse.***

FYI: EF code first with postgressql

Comment: Probably this is caused by some of the 3.0 breaking changes. Please post the `MerchantSettings` and `MasterMerchants` classes (and their fluent configuration if any) in order to tell you what's the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev. Please find the below entiies and we defined [Key] & [ForeignKey("MasterMerchants")] no other fluent configuration.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev. I mentioned few properties only for the  entities                                      public class MasterMerchants
    {
        [Key]
        public long MerchantId { get; set; }
        public string MerchantName { get; set;
        public MerchantSettings MSetting { get; set; }
    }   public class MerchantSettings
    {
        [Key]
        public long MerchantSettingId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MasterMerchants")]
        public long MerchantId { get; set; }
        public MasterMerchants Merchant { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Can't reproduce. It works for me with just classes from your comment. Note that `[ForeignKey("MasterMerchants")]` is incorrect and probably is ignored (it should specify the navigation property name associated with the FK property), so better remove it or change it to `[ForeignKey("Merchant")]`

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev Thanks again for your help on this. Let me change the FK property and update you.